# How to use azure devops python api. Need some examples: get user story info, create user story, change status

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, devops

I had a program that completely covered my requirements, I wrote it without using libraries. I accidentally deleted the file. Use version control. always.

I am trying to get a list of tasks, but I do not understand at all what I am doing. Does anyone have examples? I need several simple actions: create user story with tag, get user story info (title, desc, id), change user story status (active, closed)

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v6_0.work_item_tracking.work_item_tracking_client import WorkItemTrackingClient
import pprint

from azure.devops.v6_0.work_item_tracking.models import WorkItemBatchGetRequest
m_token = "x7micezp4c25btn3a1111111111111o23zlxuwrpdoa"

m_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/logistics/'
m_cred = BasicAuthentication('', m_token)
m_conn = Connection(base_url=m_url, creds=m_cred)
m_client = m_conn.clients.get_core_client()



kek = WorkItemBatchGetRequest(ids = [22, 33])
cc = WorkItemTrackingClient(m_url)

c = cc.get_work_items_batch(kek, "Manyport")

print(c.value)
```

Comment: The Python API is a thin wrapper around the REST API. You may find your luck there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Answer (score -1):

Thank you [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952462/tom) supporting your answer adding the screenshot on how to add the user identity in function app settings.

Rest API which provide create, retrieve, update or delete access to the service's resources also supports the HTTP operations and are service endpoints.

Below is the sample code of Rest API with HTTP client class.

```
public static async void GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        var personalaccesstoken = "PAT_FROM_WEBSITE";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
                        "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

For further information check [Azure DevOps with Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

Comment: I use python...